# How to keep recording key strokes while program not in focus (in background) in F#?

Tags: recursion, f#, background-process, keystroke

The code below is part of a bigger ML project, but I want it to run while it's minimised too. How can I do this? I think I need to run it as a windows process to achieve this, but there isn't much information on how to do that in F#. Or is there another way?

```
let rec f() =
    let c = System.Console.ReadKey().KeyChar
    printfn "%c" c
    f()
f()
```

Comment: I think you'll need to use some Win32 platform interop to capture global keyboard input.  This will likely require your application to run with elevated prvileges as well.  There's an example of doing this in C# [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/).  Let us know if you need help porting that to F#.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach That works, and I would need help porting that unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: Is the intent to run as a service or as a console application?

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach I'd rather it run as a service but it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link in Aaron's comment I decided to give the port a try. This works for me. Note that this could definitely be cleaned up a bit more.
I placed the following in a file called *NativeHooks.fs*

```
namespace Native

open System

type HookProc = delegate of int * nativeint * nativeint -> nativeint

module User32 =
    open System.Runtime.InteropServices

    [<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
    extern nativeint SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, nativeint hMod, uint32 dwThreadId)


    [<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>]
    extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk)

    [<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
    extern nativeint CallNextHookEx(nativeint hhk, int nCode, nativeint wParam, nativeint lParam)

module Kernal32 =
    open System.Runtime.InteropServices

    [<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)>]
    extern nativeint GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName)
```

My *Program.fs* then looks like so:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Diagnostics
open Native

// Credit: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/
[<Literal>]
let WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13
[<Literal>]
let WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100
let mutable hookId = IntPtr.Zero

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let sprintKey k = KeysConverter().ConvertToString(k)

    // installs a hook from WH_KEYBOARD_LL events to callback. 
    // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx
    let setHook hookProc : nativeint =
        using (Process.GetCurrentProcess()) (fun curProcess ->
        using (curProcess.MainModule) ( fun curModule ->
            let handle = Kernal32.GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName)
            User32.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, handle, (0 |> uint32))
        ))

    let callback = fun nCode wParam lParam ->
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam = (WM_KEYDOWN |> nativeint)) then
            let vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam)
            printfn "%s" (sprintKey vkCode)
        User32.CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam)

    hookId <- setHook(new HookProc(callback))
    Application.Run()
    User32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId) |> ignore    
    0
```

My *fsproj* file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="NativeHooks.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[Original solution in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/)

[Windows Hook documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know how to reference the Native namespace. I have it as a file in the same folder, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @Alanay only thing I can think of is that you don't have the file order correct. If you are learning F# this is quite a tricky one to be learning on... and the above is not very semantic F# code anyway.

Comment: I dropped a version on gist that combines them all in one file: https://gist.github.com/dburriss/6655745100c2c3eacc8eaee7898f097a