# How to catch input Event in F#

Tags: .net, input, f#

I'm trying to make an input system in F# (don't ask why, i'm kind of bored). The thing is, is there any .NET specific input buffer or message pump to fetch the keyboard (and other) devices, or do I have to go with the "classic" C style solution and `windows.h` functions?

I tried to search, but I only find Windows Form things and C++. I could still go with a C++ library for this probably, but again, I'd prefer to try something more ".NET"

Comment: Why would "Windows Form things" not work for you here? That is pretty ".NET", after all.

Comment: @JimFoye mainly because afterward i'll open a separate window for some Vulkan deep black magic

Comment: Don't see quite what you're after. If you're developing a console application, then look in Console where you have ReadKey and other things for simple console input and output. If you plan for a more GUI like experience, then there's WPF, Xamarin, and all sorts of web based solutions, and probably more I can't remember or don't know about, in addition to Windows Forms. If you want something F# specific, have a look at Elmish.WPF and Bolero, which are the ones I use. But there's also the SAFE stack and other F# specific and Elmish based.

Comment: Console app clearly, but not Console input because it's halting the pgrm, also it does not provide a valid way to have chords and is only tracking input in the Console, if I open a window with sfml for instance I won't get those.

Comment: I'd look at C# examples that run ReadKeys() on a separate thread using a Task, and use Taskbuilder.fs to get a similar API if I'm struggling to translate to async.

Comment: That's also a valid choice for continuous key reading without holding the thread but doesn't solve the problem if I open another window

Comment: I have answered something similar before. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621568/how-to-keep-recording-key-strokes-while-program-not-in-focus-in-background-in/51643344#51643344